# Flutter Ribbon style around a widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages, flutter-custompainter

I want to achieve ribbon style around widgets.

Hey guys, do anyone have any idea on how to implement this kind of style around a widget in flutter. Is there any available package for this?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a package that has something similar https://pub.dev/packages/floating_ribbon. But, I think it's not hard to implemented yourself. You will need `Stack` where the ribbon will be placed on top of your widget. You can use also `Positioned` to place the ribbon exactly where you want on top of your widget.

Comment: Hey thanks. But the text inside the ribbon could have more than 1 line. So i could not use just image. The size of the ribbon needs to be dynamic. Also this package widget is not as my requirement. Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I don't think is a good idea to have dynamic ribbon size. You don't want a ribbon to be huge and cover, let's say, a big part of your background Widget. Are you going to use it in a list with many similar ribbon widgets? Maybe is better to have a constant ribbon size and change dynamically the font size when the text is very long.